# How do I 404 redirect all links in a sub-subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

We are getting rid of some spammy inbound links to our site. This means we want to have these links resolve as '404 not found'. I am having problems sorting out the basic .htaccess modification needed to do this.

I want any links starting with 'www.example.com/cgi-bin/dir' to give a 404 code, thus I added this to my .htaccess in the www directory:

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/dir.*$ - [L,R=404]
```

I got to this line of code by combining the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730683/send-a-404-error-via-htaccess) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623565/redirect-all-links-below-a-subdirectory-to-a-out-of-service-page) question. It works fine on 'www.example.com/cgi-bin/dir' itself, but does not work for any link lower down the directory. Non-working links include links like 'http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/dir/search.cgi'. There is no .htaccess file in the cgi-bin folder, or the relevant subfolders.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an .htaccess file in the cgi-bin/dir directory. It contains these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

I'm guessing the problem was that the .htaccess in the www directory was not being read, because we were entering the cgi-bin directory, which is on the same level as the www directory, not inside it.